# Excel vba determine If the Cell is selected in a table Then run script

Tags: excel, vba

I currently run code that loops though a column of data in a table and want to modify my code below that if the cell is selected run my script/macro

```
Dim tb As Listobject
Dim Currcell, i As Integer

Set tb = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

For i = 1 To 60
    Currcell = tb.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, tb.ListColumns(1).Index)
    If Currcell = Selected Then
    ' Run My Script
End If
Next i
```

I know the code is crude but hopefully you get the idea "Currcell" suppose to represent if the cell is selected or not. Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you change the logic to only loop through any selected cells in that column:

```
If Not Intersect(tb.DataBodyRange, Selection) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Intersect(tb.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Selection).Cells
        ' do something to cell
    Next cell
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Rory almost exactly what i'm after, whats best way for me to only make my cell changes to cells selected in one particular column as at the minute this will make changes to any cell selected with in the table, as my tables are modified by end users who many accidentally select other cells in the table not belonging to the column I'm wanting to modify

Comment: Sorry - I missed that. I have amended the code accordingly.